# HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: Error 302 found

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

Since today I have the following problem while deploying a new version to Google App Engine from Eclipse:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/updatepagespeed?app_id=MY_APP_ID&version=1&
302 Found
```

Further debug info:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/updatepagespeed?app_id=MY_APP_ID&version=1&
302 Found

at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:336)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:287)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:266)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.NoLoggingClientDeploySender.send(NoLoggingClientDeploySender.java:35)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1168)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.updatePagespeed(AppVersionUpload.java:588)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:209)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:572)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:58)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I simply have no idea what is going wrong, since I did not change anything significant in my code or setup.

Anyone any clues on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the AppEngine SDK 1.9.32 seems to solve the problem (I was using 1.9.30). Updating from Eclipse did not show this update, so I downloaded it manually. Now it works again!

Hope I can help other people with this. Anyone any idea why this update is not being pushed with the Google Updater site?

**EDIT:**

About the updating:

- First download the newest App Engine SDK from Google.
- Update from Eclipse is done by 'Deploying to App Engine' -> 'App Engine Project Settings' -> 'Configure SDKs' -> 'Add...' -> 'Select folder with newest SDK'.

Simple as that!

Comment: Still after updating the SDK to 1.9.32?

Comment: Thank you so much - happened to me too, suddenly, just today.

Comment: manual upgrade to 1.9.32 fixed the problem. Could somebody post the right way to manually upgrade... my approach worked, but seems overly complicated.

Comment: Updated the answer in case you use Eclipse @RobertD